# how to compare array to see if it contains specific values

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array of values that i want to check for to see if it contains 3 specific values and if it does not, i would like to check which ones that the array does not contain.

3 values:

```
'docx', 'pdf', 'jpg'
```

array:

```
var comps = [
    { file: 'docx' },
    { file: 'pdf' },
    { file: 'txt' },
    { file: 'png' },
    { file: 'pdf' }
]
```

function:

```
function checkCodes () {
    angular.forEach( comps, function (comp) {
        if(comp.file === 'docx' && comp.file === 'pdf' && comp.file === 'jpg') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

currently i think its looping over one at a time so it always returns false based on that only 1 value is being checked at a time.

Comment: comp.file can't possibly be equal to 'docx' **and** to 'pdf'. It could be one, **or** the other, **or** something else.

Comment: Your `return false` is **inside** `forEach` block.  The very first time you find an element that does not match your condition it fires and you get your `false` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is easier

```
hasAnyDoc = comps.findIndex( f => f.file === 'docx' || f.file === 'pdf' || f.file === 'jpg' ) > -1
```